# Show another URL for the page instead of actual URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am making my project using CodeIgniter. I have changed my default URL and also removed the URL name from URL by below code:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'users';
$route['^(:any)(/:any)?$'] = "users/$0";
```

So, Now I am showing only my function name in URL like **(Method 1)**

```
www.myweb.com/function_name
```

But, What I want is when I click the button on the page and it goes to a particular function, then it should show URL Something like below instead of above-mentioned URL. **(Method 2)**

```
www.myweb.com/function_name/string1/string2
```

But It should work as normal function work in **method 1**.
Another requirement is both the strings (string1 and string2) is different for every different function. I can't figure out how to do this!

For Example:
**Controller File(Users.php):**

class Users extends CI_Controller()
{

```
public function question()
{
    //Here is my function code...
}

public function answer()
{
    //Function code
}
```

}

So, when the user submits the form it should be redirected to `www.myweb.com/question` but instead of this URL another URL should be shown like `www.myweb.com/question/myweb_subject/myweb_question` and the same rule should be applied for **answer** function.

```
www.myweb.com/answer/answer
www.myweb.com/answer/myweb_subject/myweb_answer
```

Comment: we also can't figure out what you need is. add some live examples

Comment: I want to add some extra parameter name in the URL after the function name when user calls the function.

Comment: add example code of which describe **`want to add some extra parameter name in the URL after the function name`**

Comment: I have added the example of what i want.

Comment: where these comes from `myweb_subject/myweb_answer` binding data ??

Comment: `myweb_subject` and `myweb_answer` both are getting fetched from the database after getting data using the $_POST method when the user clicks the button.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Comment: Thank you @wolfgang1983. I will try to solve this by routing.